# Camunda:Http Connector Post Method With Content-Type application/json

Tags: json, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to use data i have parsed form precious service and make post request for writing this data in another databasei in postman my post request looks like this :
[image]

and here is my http connector post request exmple:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is called **payload** and not body.

See camunda documentation about [connector](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/connect/http-connector/#using-the-generic-api).